# bind listbox items to equation

Tags: vb.net

I'm new user of VB 2010. I'm doing a simple program as a part of my Uni project 
The Idea of this program is to help user to find appropriate meals that fit with his/her calories.
There are many factors should be taken into consideration to calculate the calories.
These are Age, Weight, Height and level of activities
Then user should decide if he/she want to maintain his/her weight or lose weight
Based on all of these inputs .. meals should be shown

Actually, I build the form of the program ... and I wrote the formula to calculate the BMR which is the previous step before calculate calories. Despite this progress, I found difficulty to bind level of activities which are in "listbox" to the equation where as each level is expressing a number to add it to the equation . I don't know what should I do. Should I identify the Items of listbox first or ????

I found many materials in website and youtube, but there are nothing about what I need
I need your help

This is what I have done

```
 If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Text = (66 + (13.7 * MaskedTextBox1.Text) + (5 * MaskedTextBox2.Text) - (6.8 * MaskedTextBox3.Text))
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Text = (665 + (9.6 * MaskedTextBox1.Text) + (1.8 * MaskedTextBox2.Text) - (4.7 * MaskedTextBox3.Text))
        End If
```

Comment: I don't get what the listbox items contains. But let's say they contains the amount of calories. You should probably go with checking the data that the specific item contains on ListboxName.SelectedIndexChanged. Tell me if you need continuous help!

Comment: Thanx Alex, Actually, My listbox content 3 items ... So, when the user input his/her details, he/she have to select one of the the items. However, these items is  written as a text.. So, I need the program to transfer this selected text to number so I can add it into the equation.

Comment: For example,In my program ... If user input his/her Gender, Age, Weight, Height and he/she selected one of the items of the listbox.. the result should be (The above equation) multiply in the selected items in listbox

Comment: So basically, you need a listbox item to contain a number whilst its text is something else?
The listbox items text = "Hello World" and the "data" so to speak is "1337"? And then retrieve that number to use in the equation?

Comment: Are the three listbox items created by you (are they always there) or by the user (i.e. when a button is clicked, an item is added)?

Comment: I created ... the user should select on of them .. I would like to show u my program form but because my reputation score is 1 .. So, I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedItem = "This is item 1" Then
        'Do your math here - If you want the first item to be 1
        'then you simply use the number 1 here

        'Example: (Will display 2)
        MsgBox(1 + 1)
    ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "This is the 2:nd item" Then
        'Do your math here - If you want the first item to be 1
        'then you simply use the number 1 here

        'Example: (Will display 3)
        MsgBox(1 + 2)
    ElseIf ListBox1.SelectedItem = "This is item 3" Then
        'Do your math here - If you want the first item to be 1
        'then you simply use the number 1 here

        'Example: (Will display 4)
        MsgBox(1 + 3)
    End If
End Sub
```

So basically, if the selected item is the item to calcutate 1+1 - the code will do that "equation"

If you want the items to be dynamically added, there is another way to do it :)